# Cannot import commons io with Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, apache-commons

I'm trying to use the `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` class from commons-io. IntelliJ recognizes that it's imported, however when running the project, I get a compilation error

> Compilation error error: package org.apache.commons.io does not exist
>
> In C:\Users\Jerred\IdeaProjects\RWFMaps\app\controllers\Application.java:3

I'm importing the dependencies in sbt, it's not giving me any errors:

```
libraryDependencies += "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.5"
```

And in my class file, no errors either:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Could you please add your `build.sbt` file?

Comment: [build.sbt](http://pastebin.com/EXp0Vzph)

Comment: You are not adding `commons-io` anywhere at this build.sbt.

Comment: I added it to plugins.sbt, how do I add it to build.sbt?

Answer (score 1):

Your `build.sbt` file is not adding the commons-io dependency. Just change it to be like this:

```
name := "rwfmaps"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `rwfmaps` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    javaJdbc,
    cache,
    javaWs,
    "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.5"
)

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

When adding it to your `project/plugin.sbt` it will be available only for sbt tasks and plugins, but not for your application. `build.sbt` is where you declare runtime/compile dependencies for your application.